# PHP MySQL autocomplete

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have an auto complete search field which as the user types a name, th results are shown in the dropdown.

This all works fine, and shows the data as it should.

I am waiting to make each result a link however, so when the results are shown the user can click on the correct name and it will take them to their profile.

See script below:

```
<input type='text' id=employees class='form-control' size="80" placeholder="Search Employees by first or last name">
```

**search.php**

```
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

    $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT name_first, employee_id, unique_id, name_last FROM hr_employees WHERE name_first LIKE '{$searchTerm}%' OR name_first LIKE '{$searchTerm}%' OR employee_id LIKE '{$searchTerm}%'");
    $array = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $array[] = array (

            'value' => $row['name_first'].' '.$row['name_last'].' ('.$row['employee_id'].')',

        );
    }
    //RETURN JSON ARRAY
    echo json_encode ($array);
```

Upon selecting the correct user, I would like the user to de directed to page.php?id=$employee_id

Is this possible?

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#employees" ).autocomplete({
source: 'search.php'
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Use $row['id'] as the array index instead of 'value'. Then you have that information on the client side separated. Post your JavaScript code for further instructions.

Comment: Don't use the deprecated `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed since PHP 7. Use PDO or MySQLi instead. You are also wide open to SQL Injection attacks and should use Prepared Statements (which you can use with PDO and MySQLi).

Comment: @colburton - Thanks, would you be able to show me how I would do this in an answer?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: Thanks @tadman - But do you have any answer for my question?

Comment: Thanks @MagnusEriksson - But do you have any answer for my question?

Comment: What javascript are you using to fire the autocomplete? Add that to your question.

Answer (score 3):

As requested:

PHP:

```
$pdo        = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name_first, employee_id, unique_id, name_last FROM hr_employees WHERE name_first LIKE :search OR name_first LIKE :search OR employee_id LIKE :search");
$stmt->execute([':search' => $searchTerm.'%']);

$array = [];
while (false !== ($row = $stmt->fetch())) {
    $array[] = [
        'value' => $row['name_first'].' '.$row['name_last'].' ('.$row['employee_id'].')',
        'id'    => $row['id'],
    ];
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $( "#employees" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'search.php',
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          window.location.href = 'page.php?id='+ui.item.id;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Fiddle with console.log instead of location change: https://jsfiddle.net/dLe4a83x/

Comment: Thanks, I have added JavaScript to the question

Comment: Is that jQuery?

Comment: Sorry yes its JQuery. Updated Question

Comment: Thanks for the update, however it doesnt seem to be working, nothing is now showing in the drop down

Comment: Did you notice, that i've changed back to 'value', since that is what jQuery is expecting here.

Comment: Yes, this is now currently in my script and not working

Comment: Ok, I've added a fiddle to figure out the problem. Now it works.

Comment: Try to this code working fine **[Click hare](https://www.phpcodingstuff.com/blog/autocomplete-search-box-in-php-mysql.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use JQuery UI library to make navigation in autocomplete search Autocomplete search in PHP and Mysql. Here is the working code:

HTML form:

```
<form>
    <input id="dd_user_input" class="search_form" type="text" value="Type your Input Here"/>
</form>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(function() {

  $("#dd_user_input").autocomplete({
    source: "global_search.php?cityId=28",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var getUrl = ui.item.id;
      if (getUrl != '#') {
        location.href = getUrl;
      }
    },

    html: true,

    open: function(event, ui) {
      $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
    }
  });

});
```

Here location href is mentioned so user can navigate upon clicking this link. Here you can fetch the data of getUrl by JqueryUI which is populated by the query. For reference you can check : https://www.discussdesk.com/autocomplete-search-in-php-mysql-json-with-navigation.htm