# How to get record ID from an autocomplete search using PHP and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms, autocomplete

I am using [code from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104478/php-mysql-autocomplete) which gets me very close to the desired outcome but I'm stuck at the final step and could use some expert help please.

I am building a form (php with Xxamp) which is to comprise of a number of fields to input data to a MySQL database. The autocomplete input field is retrieving the text search results ok but I also need to obtain the 'id' value of the record which is searched for and selected.

The submit button needs to post the id value of the selected search result - not the text which is displayed.

Very grateful in advance for help.

**addnewrecord2.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Autocomplete Search Box in PHP MySQL - Php Coding Stuff</title>
 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap Css -->
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body> 

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h2>Search Here</h2>
            <input type="text" name="place" id="search" placeholder="search here...." class="form-control">  
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
     $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
       source: 'inputnewrecord2.php',
       minLength: 3,
     });
  });
</script>


<?php

if(isset($_POST['place'])){

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    // collect value of input field
    $id = $_POST['place'];

    if (empty($id)) {
        echo "Place is empty";
    } else {
        echo $id;
    }
    }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**And inputnewrecord2.php**

```
 <?php

/*
Code on this page and addrecord2.php is from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104478/php-mysql-autocomplete
Same code is also here: https://www.phpcodingstuff.com/blog/autocomplete-search-box-in-php-mysql.html
*/

require_once('include/dbconn.php');

if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
     
    $query = "SELECT TowerID, Place, Place2, Dedicn FROM tbldove WHERE Place LIKE '%{$_GET['term']}%' ORDER BY Place";

     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  
     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while ($user = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        if(empty($user['Place2'])){
            $placeDis = $user['Place'].", ".$user['Dedicn'];
        } else {
            $placeDis = $user['Place'].", ".$user['Place2'].", ".$user['Dedicn'];
        }

       //$res[] = $user['Place'].", ".$user['Place2'] ;

       $res[] = $placeDis;
       //$res[] = $user['TowerID'];
       //$res = [$placeDis,$user['TowerID']];
       //$res = array($placeDis,$user['TowerID']);

    }
     } else {
       $res = array();
     }
     //return json res
     echo json_encode($res);
 }

?>
```

[image: Image of search results in autocomplete field]

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using prepared statements to prevent [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) without it your data is at risk
In your code this is how you store the data,

```
$res[] = $placeDis;
```

But you could store it in another array with custom keys to pair the id and the place

```
$place = ['TowerID' => $user['TowerID'], 'Place' => $placeDis];

$res[] = $place;
```

In your JavaScript code, expect the returned JSON to be decoded as an Array of Objects

For Example,

```
const res = [{
              TowerID: 1,
              Place: 'Nigeria'
             }, {
              TowerID: 2,
              Place: 'Europe'
            }]
```

Then you have to iterate through the response and you can access the TowerID (`item.TowerID`) and Name (`item.Place`) of a Place

The result gotten from the PHP file will be an array of objects. So throught the forEach loop we will be able to access every item in the array.

In this case I'm adding the place to the DOM in a span element..

```
results.forEach(result => {
    const elm = document.create Element('span');
    elm.id = result.TowerID;
    elm.innerText = result.Place;

    document.body.append(elm);
});
```

Comment: Hi @a.mola. I've made the change to the array as you described but now I'm getting just lines/empty rows in the autosearch result and no data. What do I need to do to the JavaScript to get the ID and still display the text?

Comment: I've edited the answer, but the main idea is to assign the `TowerID` as the id of the element, then continue using the `Place` as the innerText of the element.

Comment: I totally get the concept but I don't understand how to code it.

Comment: Can you add your JavaScript code to the question?

Comment: It's there - about half way down the first code snippet (addnewrecord2.php).